# How to add two textview with orientation vertical(One below other) in a table row without using xml?

Tags: android, textview, tablelayout

I want add two textview with orientation vertical(One below other) in a table row without using xml that is by programatically. Can anyone suggest me how to do this? Is there any other way than this? Already there are many textviews in a tablerow(horizontally).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a `LinearLayout` in the `TableRow` cell. Put the two `TextView` widgets in the `LinearLayout`. Use Java constructors to create the `LinearLayout` and the `TextView` widgets. Use `addView()` to add the `TextView` widgets to the `LinearLayout`.